# google maps and geolocation with markers javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

i want to make a google maps that shows the current location of the user and it should also be possible that the user can click on the map to add markers. i can do them separately but it fails when i try to combine them.

this is my code for the geolocation

```
    function success(position) {
  var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
  mapcanvas.id = 'mapcontainer';
  mapcanvas.style.height = '500px';
  mapcanvas.style.width = '600px';
  document.querySelector('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);
  var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  var options = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: coords,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    navigationControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), options);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: coords,
      map: map,
      title:"You are here!"
  });
}
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
} else {
  error('Geo Location is not supported');
}
```

and this is my code to add markers to the map.

```
      var map;
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });
}

function placeMarker(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
  });

  map.setCenter(location);
}
```

Comment: Combined your scripts here: http://jsfiddle.net/xypgH/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the folllowing link..the example in it will help you surely.worked for me too.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/291499/Google-Maps-API-V3-for-ASP-NET